# Choosing A 4s BMS

Tags: bms

I am using the panasonic ncr18650pf battery in a 4s pack for my project and I want it incorporate a BMS with balance lead charging. I have already ordered the batteries and holders but I have never built a battery pack so what should the BMS be rated for (amps).

Here is a link to the datasheet.
https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/955257/Panasonic/NCR18650PF/1

Comment: The building of battery packs by  the inexperienced is highly suspect and dubious. To do this you'd first have to identify the expected current draw of whatever you are trying to power - key information that is currently missing from your question.  But you really should re-consider the lacking wisdom of attempting this project *at all*.

Comment: The current draw is about 2600 mA and I understand the concern but I still plan to build it

Comment: Take the higher of the peak load current and peak charge current, add a margin (at least 20%) and use that number for the minimum BMS rating.

Comment: thank you for the help